# How can I add a table to a graph?

Tags: r, graph, statistics, ggplot2

I have created a dodged bar chart using the following commands:

```
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) 
b = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","D") 
c = c(60,20,20,80,5,5,5,50,50,25,25,25,20,5) 
dat = data.frame(Group=a, Member=b, Percentage=c) 
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill="white", colour="black")
```

If I have a set of values:

```
table_values = c("2", "4", "2", "1")
table_total = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
tab = data.frame(Type=table_total, Value=table_values)
```

How can I add this as a table to my graph so that it is aligned? Something like this:

[image]

I can do this manually but I have a lot of graphs to generate so I was wondering if this can be automated. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can annotate with geom_text, placing the text as a slightly negative y value. This puts it into the plot area rather than below the axis.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill="white", colour="black") +
  geom_text(aes(x=table_total, label=table_values), y=-2, data=tab)
```

[image: Using geom_text to make something like a table in a graph]

I more involved approach would be to create two separate plots, one that is the bar chart, one that is the "table" (turning off almost all the theme elements) and using something like `align.plots` (not sure if that is the right name) in the `ggExtra` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect! A quick question though: When I specify -2, ggplot does not show that number on the Y-axis so everything is fine. But if I specify say -20, it does. Is there a way to make ggplot display values from 0,80 but still draw values at -20? If it is too confusing, I will try and paraphrase.

Comment: You can specify which values get labels on the axes.  For example, you can add `+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80))`

Comment: @Brian, on a complete side note, did you see your 4th bar from the left sits slightly lower than the others? Topical as we had that in our office yesterday and were trying to work out what the deal was... Wondered if you had any thoughts?

Comment: @nzcoops, It is a known bug https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/284014.html

Comment: Thanks Brian, figured it had to be a version thing as I couldn't replicate on my macbook or linux server and a colleague had issues at home on windows with the latest version (I'm on 2.13 still). Cheers.