# How can I add a table to my ggplot2 output?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a quick way to add a table to my ggplot2 graph?  I would like this table to have the value of each line at the same breakpoints as specified in `scale_x_continuous()`, but with the percentage (%) symbol next to them.   My end goal is to create something like the image below. However, I don't know how to add the table.

[image: gains chart example]

The following block of code just makes two lines in ggplot2 and should be adequate to provide me with an example:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a = seq(0, 90, 10), b = seq(10, 100, 10))
df.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = seq(1, 100, 10))) + geom_line(aes(y = a), colour = 'red') +
           geom_line(aes(y = b), colour = 'blue') + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
df.plot
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408508/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-a-graph), but the given answer is more of a workaround and wouldn't look good for a table with 2 rows.  I am going to mess around with the clues provided by Brian Diggs, but I figured I would post this in case anyone has already done something like this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Thanks to @baptiste for helping me figure this out. I posted my own response below that finished what he started.

Comment: I don't have time to really work on this, but one approach might be to use `grid.arrange` and `grid.table` from the **gridExtra** package. I suspect it will be hard to line things up nicely that way, though, without some manual tinkering.

Comment: I think the most straight-forward way is to create the table using `ggplot2` itself. This was nicely illustrated with [this example](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/) (may need updating some of the code as it's relatively old).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a basic example of the strategy used by learnr:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a = seq(0, 90, 10), b = seq(10, 100, 10))
df.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = seq(1, 100, 10))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = a), colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = b), colour = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))

# make dummy labels for the table content
df$lab <- month.abb[ceiling((df$a+1)/10)]

df.table <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = 0,
                              label = lab, colour = b)) +
  geom_text(size = 3.5) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
       panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
       axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) 

gA <- ggplotGrob(df.plot)
gB <- ggplotGrob(df.table)[6,]
gB$heights <- unit(1,"line")


require(gridExtra)
gAB <- rbind(gA, gB)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gAB)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like the correct solution.  I'm gonna work through this and see if I can build the gains plot I showed you in my picture.

Comment: there are two steps in this procedure, which can be done independently to make it easier; i) first, get the "table" plot on its own, even with axes etc if that helps; ii) align the two graphs in one page.

Comment: What exactly does the ggplotGrob() function do? the documentation is kinda crappy and I don't really know what I'm looking at in the output.

Comment: it's building the ggplot and converting it to a gtable, which is the object that will eventually get plotted. As such it contains the layout information (viewport widths, heights, etc.) that you need to align two plots. Try `names(gt)` to get a sense of what the gtable contains.

Comment: i included my own response that builds off of yours

Comment: When running this example, re-assigning widths at the end messes up the format for the table widths, so the table ends up as a single tiny vertical line, presumably everything squashed together. Replacing those 3 lines with just `gB$widths <- gA$widths` works as expected, though there's probably better ways to do that. Maybe this is a necessary fix due to a change in how grobs work over the last 3 years?

Comment: Assignment of heights does not work for me, leaving it out gives me a plot that is half plot and half table, using it gives me an error (invalid  `layout.pos.row`). If I find out how to fix this I'll post it here.

Comment: Ok, I found it out, seems `gB$heights` is a vector in current `grid` versions, but the 6th element of the vector is what we need to change here. So changing the line `gB$heights <- unit(1,"line")` to `gB$heights[6] <- unit(1, "lines")` does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a script that creates the general table that I set out to make.  Notice that I included table titles by changing the names under `scale_y_continuous` for each row.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
df <- data.frame(a = seq(0, 90, 10), b = seq(10, 100, 10))
df.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = seq(1, 100, 10))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = a), colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = b), colour = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))

# make dummy labels for the table content
lab.df <- data.frame(lab1 = letters[11:20],
                     lab2 = letters[1:10])

df.table1 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab1, y = 0,
                                 label = lab1)) +
  geom_text(size = 5, colour = "red") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Model Lift") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
        axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 5))

df.table2 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab2, y = 0,
                                 label = lab2)) +
  geom_text(size = 5, colour = "blue") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Random")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
        axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 3.84))


# silly business to align the two plot panels    
gA <- ggplotGrob(df.plot)
gB <- ggplotGrob(df.table1)
gC <- ggplotGrob(df.table2)

maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3], gC$widths[2:3])
gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gC$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)

grid.arrange(gA, gB, gC, ncol=1, heights=c(10, .3, .3))
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: nicely done. There's a bit of a mismatch on the left side, if that's a problem I'm sure it can be fixed byt looking more closely at the plot margins and widths.

Comment: it also might have something to do with the position of the titles "Model Lift" and "Random."  I bet if you messed around with the `hjust` option a bit it would go away.  The other plot I made didn't have those issues.