# Heat Table in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm looking for a way to duplicate the kind of Heat Table shown below with R (and possibly ggplot2). Specific time axis are irrelevant; any rectangular table should do.

[image]

I've tried to search for `Heat map` and `Heat table` in Google, but couldn't find any R package that did the trick.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is an R question only and should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is off-topic for this forum, see the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). This is pretty easy in ggplot2, check out the geom_point examples in the docs, mappings for x and y axis should be self explanatory, you just need to map some numeric variable to size, and some other factor to color. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32014/1036) for just one example of many.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(vaxis = rep(c(letters[1:5], "top"), each = 4),
                 haxis = rep(c(letters[6:8], "right"), times = 6),
                 value = rpois(24, lambda = 10))
df$color <- factor(ifelse(df$vaxis == "top" | df$haxis == "right", 1, 0))
ggplot(df, aes(x = haxis, y = vaxis, size = value, color = color)) + geom_point()
```

Just get your data in a similar format. You could write a function to make the "top" and "right" values normalized marginal sums. Of course lots of tweaks are possible in naming, legends, theme, etc.

[image: plot]

Comment: Just to add to this, if you specifically want some of the points outside of the plot area (like the green ones in your original example), you could use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680063/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-my-ggplot2-output).