# Creating R tables with embedded graphics

Tags: r, excel, knitr, conditional-formatting, sweave

I'd like to be able to create a table with one of the columns being graphical, others text.  Ideally, I'd create an excel spreadsheet, but I'm pretty sure that none of the R to Excel packages can write PDFs into cells.  I think I can hack something together using Knittr or Sweave, though I don't know how, exactly.  Any advice?

Comment: What would make this question better would be if you gave a small, reproducible example. Give us a small bit of data, show us how you generate the table in Knitr or Sweave without the the image, and give us an example of the image you want to put in.

Comment: Well, the trouble is, I haven't yet used Knitr or Sweave once, so I can't generate even such an example quickly.  However, this is what I want it to look like in excel, more or less.  The graphs will be fancier (ggplot)
http://media.juiceanalytics.com/images/blog/excel_positivenegative.gif

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680063/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-my-ggplot2-output

Comment: do you have one graphic per row, or a single graphic to align with all rows?

Comment: Regarding the idea of adding text to ggplot2, this may work, but it's awkward, as many rows won't have any plot (they shouldn't), so in other words, I'd be plotting a table as a graph, even when I don't need a graph.  But it may be a workaround....

Comment: Actually, converting the table to plot format and arranging via grid.arrange is NOT a good option: I need the text to be selectable.

Comment: So, if I was doing this i would use Sweave and Latex.  Unfortunatley that has a quite steep learning curve.  I'm not aware of xtable (the goto R command to create latex tables) being able to add graphics so you'd be stuck creating the table in latex and adding the graphics via R.  That would be easiest with a fixed table format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your example :

[image: your example]

So I've looked into the R dataset, and used a baseball dataset, though I have the nagging doubt that for baseball players, the g-r might look really stupid...

Anyway I produced two examples of the use of the `get_bar_df` function, and tried to comment my script as much as possible to help you use it.

[image: two examples with bars]

The script is a standalone sweave script that you need to run using knitr or sweave

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/
\newlength{\maxlen}
\newcommand{\databarright}[2][gray!25]
{%
    \settowidth{\maxlen}{\maxnum}%
    \addtolength{\maxlen}{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%
    \FPeval\result{round(#2/\maxnum:4)}%
    \rlap{\color{#1}\hspace*{\dimexpr-\tabcolsep+0.1\arrayrulewidth}\rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}}%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth][r]{\phantom{XXX}}%
}

\newcommand{\databarleft}[2][red!25]
{%
    \settowidth{\maxlen}{\maxnum}%
    \addtolength{\maxlen}{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%
    \FPeval\result{round(#2/\maxnum:4)}%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth][r]{\phantom{XXX}}%
    \llap{\color{#1}\rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}\hspace*{\dimexpr-\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}}%    
}
\begin{document}
<<load_libraries, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results ="hide">>=
library(knitr) 
library(xtable)
@
<<get_bar_df, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results ="hide">>=
#' @title get_databar creates labels for xtable in a dataframe
#' @description It will create two new columns and fill them with values for xtable, it will use the last column
#' @param data the dataframe
#' @param colorpos one color for positive values that is interpretable by the xcolor dvips
#' one of 68 standard colors known to dvips  \link{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors}, default "grey"
#' @param colorneg one color for negative values default "red"
#' @param transparent, the percentage of transparency passed to labels default 50 use zero for no transparency
#' @param caption, caption passed to xtable. 
#' @param vline, add a vertical line at the end of the table  default FALSE
#' @return A dataframe with the last two columns edited for xtable
get_bar_df <- function(data,
    colorpos = "grey",
    colorneg="red",
    transparent=50,
    caption="",
    vline=FALSE)
{
  if (transparent!=0){
    colorpos <- paste0(colorpos,"!",transparent)
    colorneg <- paste0(colorneg,"!",transparent)
  }
  the_col <- ncol(bsb)
  idxneg <- data[,the_col] < 0
  idxpos <- data[,the_col] > 0
  data[idxneg,"\\phantom{neg}"] <- paste0("\\databarleft[",colorneg,"]{", -data[idxneg,the_col],"}")
  data[idxpos,"\\phantom{pos}"] <- paste0("\\databarright[",colorpos,"]{", data[idxpos,the_col],"}")
  maxnum <<- max(abs(data[,the_col])) # value assigned in .GlobalEnv for later use by latex
  if (!vline) {
  xdata <-xtable(data, align = rep("l",ncol(data)+1), caption = caption)  
  } else {
      xdata <-xtable(data, align = c(rep("l",ncol(data)),"|l"), caption = caption)    
  }
  return(xdata)
} 
@
<<test, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results ="hide">>=
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
bsb <- select(baseball, id, year, g, r) %>% filter(year == 1872) %>% transform(gr = g - 
            r)
bsb1 <- select(baseball, id, year, g, r) %>% filter(year == 1873) %>% transform(gr = g - 
            r)
xbsb <- get_bar_df(data = bsb, caption="example with default values")
xbsb1 <- get_bar_df(data = bsb1, 
    colorpos = "MidnightBlue",
     colorneg = "Goldenrod", 
    transparent = 60, 
    caption = "Another example with MidnightBlue, Goldenrod, transparent= 60, vline=TRUE",
    vline=TRUE)
print.xtable(xbsb, sanitize.text.function = identity, file = "bsb.tex", hline.after = NULL, include.rownames =FALSE)
print(xbsb1, sanitize.text.function = identity, file = "bsb1.tex", hline.after = NULL, include.rownames =FALSE)
@
% this must come after the chunk (maxnum is defined in the chunk)
\newcommand{\maxnum}
{%
    \Sexpr{maxnum}
}

\input{bsb.tex}
\input{bsb1.tex}  
\end{document}
```

Some of the code comes from this excellent post :
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/partially-coloring-cell-background-with-histograms