# Rmarkdown - Add colorbar to table for pdf and html

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, sparklines

I am trying to add a barplot to a table using Rmarkdown. I got it working for HTML.

**The HTML table works perfectly**

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
table <- as.data.frame(rbind(a,b)) #Demo table for this example
summary_column <- c(40,60) #A summary column, showing 40% and 60%.

#add the summary column using background-color
table[["summary_column"]] <- paste0( 
  "<span style='display: block; border-radius: 4px; padding-right: 4px; background-color: #00457C; color:white; width:",
  summary_column,"%;>", #Size of bar depends on the value of the vector summary_column
  summary_column,"%","</span>") #The bar has an overlaying valuelabel

library(pander)
pandoc.table(table) #convert the table to html table
```

Can also be achieved with the formattable package (my code is almost identical to theirs).

[image: Result HTML table]

**My problem is however**
How can I get this barplot to work when I knit to pdf (or Word for that matter)? I don't want to convert the table to an image because I need the interactivity in the table. I thought using an `<img>` html tag might work for the pdf, but it doesn't (works in HTML however):

```
table[["summary_column"]] <- paste0( #add summary column
  "<img src='bar.bmp'>") #add the bar.bmp to the column
```

Where bar.bmp is a 5x10px img that I would scale up to X%.
The pdf will not display background-color nor img.

[image: Resulting table when I knit to pdf]

Should I add a column with HTML code for the bar and some Tex code for the bar? My knowledge of Latex is limited.

Is there no way to let the latex engine (xelatex) read css or html tags?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the `sparkTable` package can help. [Here's a vignette](http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/PubDat_228663.pdf).

Comment: HTML markup will only work in HTML document -- `pandoc` will not convert that to PDF or docx. If you do not want to convert the whole table to an image, you can convert eg the small bar to image (eg via `sparkTable`) and refer to that with markdown -- which would work OK in HTML, PDF, docx etc as well.

Comment: Ok I did not no I could convert the bar to an image with sparkTable. If that works for html, pdf and Word that would be perfect.

Comment: If anyone can demonstrate how to add a single **horizontal** bar to a cell in pdf I would be very thankful.  I have been able to create a bar/line...chart in a cell with the sparkTable package and display it in the pdf as well as HTML. I tried to open up the sparkTable function for barchart to see how it creates the image for pdf, but without any luck.

Comment: @Helgi  I provided an example in this post [partially-color-cell-background-data-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595296/r-markdown-pdf-partially-color-cell-background-data-bar/47085376#47085376). Thanks for the html example.

Comment: And there is also one  [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623866/creating-r-tables-with-embedded-graphics/47119715#47119715)

Comment: Thanks @cedric, that looks very good. I can definitely use that