# annotate text into x axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)

head(mtcars)


# create the plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"))+
      xlab("number of cyl") + ylab("Count")
```

Now we can obtain the average `$mpg` per `cyl` with:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, FUN=mean)
```

How can I put these average values into the x-axis so that they appear below the corresponding `cyl`. Can one draw a table and somehow write that this is the ...average mpg per cyl...

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680063/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-my-ggplot2-output

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `facet_grid` instead of `ggtitle()` to put a title on the plot? This may add unneccessary complexity to a potential answer.

Comment: No, lets remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it by rewriting the factor level names:

(Note that this is safe only as long as `aggregate` generates it table in the same order as the factor level names and without any gaps - which seems like it should be the case, but one would have to investigate to make sure. It might be safer to code it as a loop and look at the level names to make sure they match up correctly)

```
library(ggplot2)

head(mtcars)

adf <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, FUN=mean)
mtcars$fcyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
levels(mtcars$fcyl) <- sprintf("%d \n %.1f",adf$cyl,adf$mpg)

# create the plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fcyl)) + geom_bar() + theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"))+
  xlab("number of cyl") + ylab("Count")
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any comments?