# R ggplot2, display the number of subjects at the bottom (outside) of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem of displaying the # of Subjects, presented as below, at each time point for each group at the bottom but outside the plot. Could you please guide. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Relevant: [How can I add a table to my ggplot2 output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680063/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-my-ggplot2-output)

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much. @markus